# Select distinct from user_id with minimum date and all rest user fields using sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

let's say I have a table:

```
USER_ID   DATE    EXT_DATA1   EXT_DATA2   EXT_DATA3   EXT_DATA4    EXT_DATA5
   11    031213     77           aa          bb         cc            dd
   11    031213     77           aa          bb         cc            dd
   11    041213     77           aa          bb1        cc            dd1
   11    051213     78           aa          bb2        cc1           dd2
   12    040313     79           aa          bb4        cc            dd
```

I tried to get unique user_id with MIN date and all rest fields:

```
 SELECT MIN(DATE) AS ACTUAL_DATE,USER_ID,EXT_DATA1,EXT_DATA2,EXT_DATA3,EXT_DATA4,EXT_DATA5 /
 GROUP BY EXT_DATA1,EXT_DATA2,EXT_DATA3,EXT_DATA4,EXT_DATA5 ;
```

but because I have different values in columns EXT_DATA1 ,EXT_DATA2 and etc

I get  duplicates in final results :

```
  USER_ID   DATE    EXT_DATA1   EXT_DATA2   EXT_DATA3   EXT_DATA4    EXT_DATA5
    11    041213     77           aa          bb1        cc            dd1
    11    051213     78           aa          bb2        cc1           dd2
    12    040313     79           aa          bb4        cc            dd
```

Edited to fix mistake in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it do the work :

```
SELECT ACTUAL_DATE,USER_ID,EXT_DATA1,EXT_DATA2,EXT_DATA3,EXT_DATA4,EXT_DATA5
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT "DATE" AS ACTUAL_DATE,
   USER_ID,EXT_DATA1,EXT_DATA2,EXT_DATA3,EXT_DATA4,EXT_DATA5,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY "DATE" ) as rn
   FROM table_name
 )a
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

**UPDATE**

Since `DATE` is a keyword in Oracle, it needs escaping (with double quotes). Query uses analytic (or windowing) function [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100) to get the first row (sorted by date) for each user

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering me , I just learn the sql , can you please add some comments ?

Comment: Not sure if I'm right , but I'm getting error missing expression

Comment: You probably getting error because "date" is a reserved word. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice solution. I'm curious what means a letter "a" after bracket -> ")a" ? I thought that's "AS a" , but putting AS produce error.

Comment: "a" here is an alias for inline view/derived table (subquery in "FROM" clause). It's not really required in Oracle, but other RDMS complain if it's omitted.

Comment: You motivated me to start learn analytic functions . Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.USER_ID,
  t1.DATE,
  t1.EXT_DATA1,
  t1.EXT_DATA2,
  t1.EXT_DATA3,
  t1.EXT_DATA4,
  t1.EXT_DATA5
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID
  AND t1.DATE > t2.DATE
WHERE t2.USER_ID IS NULL
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f46f7/5)</kbd>

Note: This may return more than one row for each user_id if the smallest date is present in multiple rows.

Comment: Way better than my query. And I suppose you can solve the duplicate `user_id` problem by wrapping this query in another and performing another group by.

Comment: Thank you for nice answer . My case exactly when smallest date presents in multiple rows , my fault I didn't describe well the problem . So what can we do ?

Comment: @Toren Try what I suggested. Wrap Filipe Silva's query like so: `SELECT * FROM (Filipe Silva's query) outerQuery GROUP BY (list of columns)`. Note: there might be a better way to do it, this is but one option (only one I can think of at the moment).

Comment: @Toren. To get rid of duplicates when they have the same date, you have to decide what is the row that you want. You might need to join again with different columns to get that record, but you have to look at those duplicates and find a recipe for the ones you want returned.